# Creating a retention cohort by date of acquistion in R

Tags: r

I'm new to R have gone through several tutorials online and paid but still struggling with the implementation of my requirement. I would like to build a retention cohort in R. I currently do this in excel, which takes me 4-5 hours every time I need to implement one. Therefore, exploring to see if R can help out. It seems so but need some direction.

Below is the output in excel. If you notice May 2011 I had 31 customers who joined and their progression monthwise till the current month.

[Output in excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dgLs.png)

[This is the input variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ym15r.png)

Initial columns are customer id, his date of joining, and his date of expiry. Two additional columns convert the `dj` & `de` to text. Columns `K` onwards is processing of the data to check if the customer is active in given month or has he churned? I use date of join in text from to indicate active and append it to with "C" to denote expiry. Later I just count the columns with the date to get the cohort.

So, how do I implement this in R.

Assuming this is the sample data and I need the cohort from 1 May 2015 to 1 Jan 2016

```
customer dj         exp
abc      01/05/15   25/6/15
efg      01/05/15   25/7/15
ghd      01/05/15   25/7/15
mkd      01/06/15   25/7/15
kskm     01/06/15   05/8/15
```

This is what I would like to create from the above data.

```
Cohort      M0      M1      M2      M3    M4  
2015-05     3       3       2       0     0
2015-06     2       2       1       1     0
```

Explanation: M0 is the months from the date of joining. So 3 people joined us in 2015 May and all of them are active in May. M1 would be June and all of them are active in June. We lose 1 customer in the end of June on the 25th, so will consider him active in June but in M2 my count drops from 3 to 2. M3 for the May joined customers correspond to the month of August in which we have lost our customers.

Similar process of 2015-06 cohort. M1 would be the month of July and M3 the month of September.

Answer (score 1):

Modified your code as below, this works thanks! Now trying to figure out a way to make M0 to M(n) dynamic.

```
library(readxl)
library(zoo)
library(plyr)

# Read in the data
df <- read.csv("~/Desktop/R/data.csv")
df$dj <- as.Date(df$dj,"%d/%m/%y")
df$exp <- as.Date(df$exp,"%d/%m/%y")

# The data in the file has different variable names than your example data
# so I'm changing them to match
names(df)[1:3] <- c("customer","dj","exp")

# Make a variable called Cohort that contains only the year and month of joining
# as.yearmon() comes from the 'zoo' package
df$Cohort <- as.yearmon(df$dj)

# Calculate the difference in months between date of expiry and date of joining
df$MonthDiff <- ceiling((df$exp-df$dj)/30)
#df$MonthDiff <- 12*(as.yearmon(df$exp+months(1))-df$Cohort)

# Use ddply() from the 'plyr' package to get the frequency of subjects that are
# still active after 0, 1, 2, 3, and 4 months.
df1 <- ddply(df,.(Cohort),summarize,
             M0 = sum(MonthDiff > 0),
             M1 = sum(MonthDiff > 1),
             M2 = sum(MonthDiff > 2),
             M3 = sum(MonthDiff > 3),
             M4 = sum(MonthDiff > 4),
             M5 = sum(MonthDiff > 5)
             )
df1

df1
    Cohort M0 M1 M2 M3 M4 M5
1 May 2015  3  3  2  0  0  0
2 Jun 2015  2  2  1  0  0  0
```

Now

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
library(readxl)
library(zoo)
library(plyr)

# Read in the data
df <- read_excel("MyFile.xlsx")

# The data in the file has different variable names than your example data
# so I'm changing them to match
names(df)[1:3] <- c("customer","dj","exp")

# Make a variable called Cohort that contains only the year and month of joining
# as.yearmon() comes from the 'zoo' package
df$Cohort <- as.yearmon(df$dj)

# Calculate the difference in months between date of expiry and date of joining
df$MonthDiff <- 12*(as.yearmon(df$exp)-df$Cohort)

# Use ddply() from the 'plyr' package to get the frequency of subjects that are
# still active after 0, 1, 2, 3, and 4 months.
df1 <- ddply(df,.(Cohort),summarize,
             M0 = sum(MonthDiff >= 0),
             M1 = sum(MonthDiff >= 1),
             M2 = sum(MonthDiff >= 2),
             M3 = sum(MonthDiff >= 3),
             M4 = sum(MonthDiff >= 4))

df1
#   Cohort M0 M1 M2 M3 M4
# May 2015  3  3  2  0  0
# Jun 2015  2  1  0  0  0
```

This assumes that when you read the data in from Excel, the dates are formatted as dates.  In case they are not you could use the following:

```
df$dj <- as.Date(df$dj,"%d/%m/%y")
df$exp <- as.Date(df$exp,"%d/%m/%y")
```

Comment: Hi Sam thanks for the post and sorry for the confusion. I have made the description clearer. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way the analysis months M0,M1,M2 etc. be made dynamic? I was trying to implement by subracting the maximum expiry from minimum datejoined then dividing the result by 30 to get the number coloumns I would need.

Comment: Hi Sam should the june cohort be 2 2 1 1 0 rather than 2 1 0 0 0

Comment: Hi Sam could you help in creating M0 to M5 columns dynamic?